# Div will not stay in fixed position

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to have my div follow the screen, however it's not doing so - and I think it's because I have it placed in another div. Here is my css code. If it can't be fixed through css, I'm open to jquery solutions:

[Here's the live example](http://makehugeprofit.com/index.php?p=blog2)

```
.savebar {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 34px;
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #333;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move it out of the `#content-wrapper` div, seems to be working on Chrome.

Comment: Hey thanks, Unfortunately I cannot :). I'm looking for an alternative solution. Maybe jquery?

Comment: Hmm, you can use jQuery to reposition the div everytime the user scrolls. But why not just move it out of `#content-wrapper` ?